# Doctrine2 - parent, children and sibling users like

Tags: doctrine-orm, tree, siblings, multiple-users

after some research i'm still stuck finding a solution to my little problem!
I would like to have a kind of pyramidal hirarchical structure for my users, but with a notion of 'sibling users', let me explain.

I have users like that:

the tree means only who created who, in fact both building-admin manage the same building and must see what the other have created.

legend:

b=> building, s=>service, r=>room, a=> admin (with his id)

- b1-a1

  - b1-s1-a2

    - b1-s1-r1-a2
    - b1-s1-r2-a3
  - b1-s1-a4

    - b1-s1-r1-a5
    - b1-s1-r2-a6
  - b1-s2-a7
- b1-a8

  - b1-s1-a9
  - b1-s2-a10

    - b1-s2-r1-a11

And my question is, how could i achieve an access on different items depending of which user i am?

Exemple:

'b1-s2-a7' should be able to see the b1-s2-r1-a11 because he's below him even if he's not in his direct tree.

also, 'b1-s1-a9' should see what was created by his 'siblings' 'b1-s1-a2' and 'b1-s1-a4'.

I have started to try with the path structure, but i would like your opinions and advices for not going in the wrong way !

Thanks by advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would read the [doctrine docs on hierarchical data](http://doctrine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/manual/hierarchical-data.html). I used the [extensions bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html) and a nested set for something similar.

Now, regarding certain users being able to see nodes. I don't think that sounds like an issue for your database manager. I think it sounds more like business logic that you can put in your code. The extensions bundle provides some nice functions for only fetching child nodes which I think you could wrap in some convenient service for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks! I've checked it and now i think i'll be able to achieve what i want !